# Logic problem to display 3 type of image in php

Tags: php, file, display

I made a web site where people can post images and the site display every image automatically with a foreach and a for loop, I made it to display the older image at the bottom and the new more at the top, like instagram or facebook. The site worked perfectly with only to type of pictures png and jpg, but I added the jpeg and now it doesn't work, if there is a new jpeg added, we don't see any picture that has been posted before. To upload a pictures im using the w3school way : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Here is what I made:

```
<?php
      // filename = photo/NAME.png
      foreach (glob("photo/*.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename)
      {
        $numberPhoto++;
      }
      echo "<script>console.log('Il y a $numberPhoto images');</script>";

      for ($i = $numberPhoto; $i > 0; $i--)
      {
        $filePath = "photo/$i.png";
        if (file_exists($filePath))
        {
        echo "<script>console.log('+1 img et cest $i.png');</script>
        <div class='imgContainer'>
          <hr class='leftrow'>
          <div class='img'>
            <img class='theImg' src='$filePath'>
            <a href='$filePath' download='$filePath'>
              <button class='btn'><i class='fa fa-download' alt=''></i> Télécharger</button>
            </a>
            <hr class='botrow'>
        </div>
            <hr class='rightrow'>
        </div>
        <script>console.log('Image $i.png ajouté');</script>
        ";
        break;
        }

        $filePath = "photo/$i.jpg";
        if (file_exists($filePath)){
          echo "<script>console.log('+1 img et cest $i.jpg');</script>
          <div class='imgContainer'>
            <hr class='leftrow'>
            <div class='img'>
              <img src='$filePath'>
              <a href='$filePath' download='$filePath'>
                <button class='btn'><i class='fa fa-download' alt=''></i> Télécharger</button>
              </a>
              <hr class='botrow'>
          </div>
              <hr class='rightrow'>
          </div>
          <script>console.log('Image $i.jpg ajouté');</script>
          ";
        }
        else{
          $filePath = "photo/$i.jpeg";
          echo "<script>console.log('+1 img et cest $i.jpeg');</script>
          <div class='imgContainer'>
            <hr class='leftrow'>
            <div class='img'>
              <img src='$filePath'>
              <a href='$filePath' download='$filePath'>
                <button class='btn'><i class='fa fa-download' alt=''></i> Télécharger</button>
              </a>
              <hr class='botrow'>
          </div>
              <hr class='rightrow'>
          </div>
          <script>console.log('Image $i.jpeg ajouté');</script>
          ";
        }
      }
      ?>
```

I've tried this:

```
if (file_exists($filePath))
{
// png
}
else if (!file_exists($filePath))
{
// jpg
}
else if (!file_exists($filePath))
{
// jpeg
}
```

I've tried this too

```
if (file_exists($filePath))
{
// png
}
else if (!file_exists($filePath))
{
// jpg
}
else
{
// jpg
}
```

And a lot of other things that I don't remember...

My brain is like freezing when I'm trying to solve this problem I don't really know what I should do to solve this

Answer (score 1):

First, you might need to re-structure your code in a way to be productive and re-usable.
I managed to fix your code without repeating codes again, please try:

```
<?php
  // filename = photo/NAME.png

  $photos = glob("photo/*.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);

  // to sort by modified date
  usort($photos, function($a,$b){return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);});

  $numberPhoto = count($photos);

  foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $extension = pathinfo($photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo $extension;

    switch($extension){
        case 'jpg':
            $filePath = $photo; // do your logic for each type if you want
            break;

        case 'png':
            $filePath = $photo; // do your logic for each type if you want
            break;

        case 'jpeg':
            $filePath = $photo; // do your logic for each type if you want
            break;

        default:
            $filePath = $photo; // do your logic for each type if you want
    }

    echo "<script>console.log('+1 img et cest '" . $filePath . ");</script>
    <div class='imgContainer'>
      <hr class='leftrow'>
      <div class='img'>
        <img class='theImg' src='$filePath'>
        <a href='$filePath' download='$filePath'>
          <button class='btn'><i class='fa fa-download' alt=''></i> Télécharger</button>
        </a>
        <hr class='botrow'>
    </div>
        <hr class='rightrow'>
    </div>
    <script>console.log('Image '" . $filePath . " ajouté');</script>
    ";

  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thx this is working, but this code don't display them with a specific order older at the bottom of the page and the new at the top like on instagram and could you explain me the default in the switch ? I don't really understand how it can be useful

Comment: You can sort by `modified_date` by adding this line after the `glob` line:
`usort($photos, function($a,$b){return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);});`

Comment: $photos = glob("photo/*.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
  usort($photos, function($a,$b){return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);});
  $numberPhoto = count($photos);                  I made this and it's stil not working, can I simply do it as I did before with a fror loop that count reverse

Comment: By which flag you want to sort it and asc or desc ?

Comment: I sorted it with `modified_date` in a desc order now, please check

Comment: Thx it worked, this is because in your comment that was  a - b Thx a lot :)